# Java- data structures stack: printing out integers from a stack from user input

Tags: java, stack

I am writing a program which allows the user to enter a list of positive integers(terminated by a 0) in a stack and displays them in reverse order. I am first trying to print out the elements of the stack to test it first but the program is not printing out the elements when I enter 0.
Here is my program:

```
import java.util.*;
public class MyClass{

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner sc= new Scanner(System.in);

    Stack<Integer> addToStack= new Stack<Integer>();

   int num;
   System.out.println("Enter the a list of positive integers. Terminate with a 0.");
   num= sc.nextInt();
   while(num!=0){

       addToStack.push(num);

   }
    System.out.println("Displaying numbers from the stack "+ addToStack);
  }
}
```

Comment: `num= sc.nextInt();` should be in side the loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Taking user inputs**

You can use an infinite loop to take user input and break the loop when input is 0.

**Sorting user inputs**

When you needs to sort the input according to the reverse order. So you you can use default java collection sorting method `Collections.sort(List,Compartor)` which is provided in `Collections` class.

Use following code.

```
class MyClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        Stack<Integer> addToStack = new Stack<Integer>();

        int num;
        do {
            System.out.print("Enter the a list of positive integers. Terminate with a 0.");
            num = sc.nextInt();
            addToStack.push(num);
        } while (num != 0);

        //sort reverse order 
        Collections.sort(addToStack, Collections.reverseOrder());

        System.out.print(addToStack);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! But I guess I'll have to use pop() as I am not really allowed to use methods of the Collections class which kind of serve as shortcuts

Comment: Do you need to implement custom sorting method using sorting algorithm?

Comment: Normally, you show him the issue not do his homework :)

Answer (score 2):

You weren't control your entered number in loop.

Change your while condition with these `while ((num = sc.nextInt()) != 0) {`

And the result is now :

```
Enter the a list of positive integers. Terminate with a 0.
1
2
0
Displaying numbers from the stack [1, 2]
```

Answer (score 1):

You have an infinite loop. You have to re-ask the user for a new Integer, otherwise you will keep looping indefinetily

```
while(num!=0){
    addToStack.push(num);
    num= sc.nextInt();
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Good explanation

Answer (score 1):

Your code will run infinitely.You have to write `num= sc.nextInt();` inside the loop.

e.g:

```
while(num!=0){
    addToStack.push(num);
    num= sc.nextInt();
}
```